# How can I remove all entries of a factor when the number of entires without values in a column is below a threshold?

Tags: r

I have a dataset that is laid out similarly to the example below:

```
variable  value  flag
A         6.1 
A         7.0
A         3.3    x
A         5.2
A         9.5
B         1.1
B         1.0    x
B         1.0    x
B         3.4 
B         1.0    x
C         20
C         35
C         17
C         24
C         12
```

What I want to do is to remove all entries of a factor from the variable column if the number of entries WITHOUT an "x" in the flag column is less than 3.

For the data above, the desired output is below. All entries of factor B have been removed because there were only two entries without an "x" in the flag column.

```
variable  value  flag
A         6.1 
A         7.0
A         3.3    x
A         5.2
A         9.5
C         20
C         35
C         17
C         24
C         12
```

The threshold (3 in the above example) needs to be hard coded.

I have a bit of code also in use which removes all entries for factors which have fewer than 6 entries, but couldn't figure out how to adapt it for what I need.

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  filter(n() > 5)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should not remove row 7 and 8, since they do not fulfill the criteria of not having "x".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter on the value of `sum(flag != 'x')`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  filter(sum(flag != 'x') >= 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that only row6 and row10 qualifies to be deleted, since they are the only one that fulfills the criteria not having "x" in flag and being less than 3.

When comes to you origin dataframe, You should not remove row 7 and 8, since they do not fulfill the criteria of not having "x".

```
# Find out which rows to be removed.
rows_to_remove <- which(df1$value < 3 & !df1$flag == "x")

# Split finding of rows into standalone objects.
row_first <- rows_to_remove[1]
row_second <- rows_to_remove[2]

# Delete rows, keep old dataframe [df1] as reference.
# Construct a new dataframe with deleted objects [df2].
df2 <- df1[-c(row_first, row_second), ]
```